# Thermostat jumper wire missing

Tags: thermostat

I am missing my jumper wire on my thermostat. What do I replace it with?

I have been researching how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Small wire. It's not critical. Thermostat wire is often #18 solid. You could use a paperclip or a twist-tie, although copper would be better in terms of bend tolerance and connection integrity.

You could clip an unused conductor in your thermostat wire bundle and use that, or you could shorten a wire that's in use.